# Trying to redirect using <a> tag, and id & href attributes

Tags: html

I have 3 HTML files, all in the same Web page:  body1.html, body2.html and body3.html

When pointing to body1.html, for 1 particular item, I want a click to go to a particular id in body3.html; and then I want the item in body3.html to redirect to body2.html

In body1.html I have:
`<a href="body3.html#3.0">3.0</a>`

In body3.html I have:
`<a id="3.0" href="body2.html#3.0"> </a>`

In body2.html I have:
`<a id="3.0">3.0</a>`

I would expect this to work but it doesn't.  Clicking in body1.html does go to body3.html, but the redirection to body2.html is not performed.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to do what I want using HTML only?

Comment: will `<a>` auto-redirect without clicking?

Comment: @Han Han, it's beginning to look like it will not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is that the id attribute in HTML is meant to start with a letter (A-Z or a-z) and can be followed by a combination of letters, digits (0-9), hyphens, underscores, colons, and periods. Using numeric values as id attributes goes against the HTML specification.

To achieve the desired behavior, you can modify your code as follows:

```
<a href="body3.html#item3">3.0</a>
<a id="item3" href="body2.html#item3"></a>
<a id="item3">3.0</a>
```

By using valid id attributes, the redirection from body3.html to body2.html should work as expected.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  But, thanks for pointing out I'm not following the HTML specs.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure that the relative paths are correct. If your HTML files are in the same directory, your current paths should work. If they are in different directories, you might need to adjust the paths accordingly.
- Check if the file names are case-sensitive. If your server is case-sensitive, make sure that the file names in your links exactly match the case of the actual file names.

Also try playing around code like this and see how it goes.

```
<!-- body1.html -->
<a href="body3.html#3.0">3.0</a>

<!-- body3.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Body 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=body2.html#3.0">
</head>
<body>
    <a id="3.0" href="#">Link to body2.html</a>
</body>
</html>

<!-- body2.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Body 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="3.0">3.0</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Do let me know how it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Linux.  I double-checked the filenames - they're ok.  And I tried preceding the filenames with ./ with the same result.  When I used your script the clickable link "Link to body2.html" showed when body3.html displayed.  It did not auto-redirect, but when I clicked on the link it did direct to where it was supposed to go.  I need auto-redirect and I need it to work in HTMl only.

Comment: Edited the answer. Try that. And also this method is considered a clean solution, and relying solely on HTML for this type of behavior will not cover all scenarios and browser behaviors consistently. Using JavaScript provides more control and flexibility in handling such navigation scenarios.

Comment: Yes, that worked.  However, I have multiple clickable links in body1.html pointing to various places in body3.html and clicking on any of the links in body1.html auto-redirects to body2.html.  Also, clicking directly on the filename body3.html auto-redirects to body2.html.  I want to auto-redirect only for id="3.0" in body3.html.  I need to keep this as simple as possible since I need to insert the auto-redirection for specific items here and there on the fly.

Comment: Yes, I get it. As per your requirement, I suggest you use javascript. It would be minimal js but will be robust solution. Do you need it?

Comment: You can avoid javascript but for that you have to duplicate code and if there are more section, it would be hectic to maintain and is a lengthy approach.

Comment: My project is full-stack using HTML, CSS & node.js (and some JS on the client side).  In this particular case I'm creating the HTML in node.  After thinking more about this I'm going to try a different approach.  I appreciate the help and the time you've given me.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. I suggest you write minimal JS on the client side. This would make your HTML code dynamic and short and readable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is you cannot auto-redirect in an `<a>` tag.